# Changing variable does not affect results

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to create a background subtractor with the algorithm backgroundSubtractorKNN and I have a problem with the function apply. This function has an attribute called `learningRate`, but if I change the value of this rate nothing happens in my results.
Does anybody know what is happening?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv    
import numpy as np

learningRate=0.05
fgbg= cv.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN() 
cap=cv.VideoCapture('some_video.mp4')

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Unable to open: ')
    exit(0)

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        print("me voy")
        break
    frame=cv.resize(frame,(320,240)) 
    fgmask=fgbg.apply(frame,learningRate)
    
    cv.imshow('Frame',frame)
    cv.imshow('FG MASK Frame',eroded2)

    keyboard=cv.waitKey(30)

    if keyboard=='q' or keyboard ==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please consider editing the title to describe the question better.